# can't find IP address for open nagios in browser

Tags: installation, ip, nagios

I downloaded `nagios` for `vmware player` and installed it,
but I can't open it on my browser because I can't find the ip address.
thanks. [Look at the screenshot. You can see there is no IP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE2Op.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click on nagios in vmware startup and check setting
- in hardware , go to network adapter
- in network connecton, change it to NAT : used to share the host's IP address
- click ok and start you vm, ip address should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an IP on the nagios host? If not, you may need one statically or via DHCP.